# Best widget toolkit for developing desktop environment for xserver?

Tags: qt, operating-system, widget

Suggest a good widget toolkit to devlop GUI. I've worked with QT, GTK+ and X11, wikipedia shows a lot, is there anything better than than qt? To work with multi touch computing. I cannot start from the scratch with X11, and gtk is tough, QT is easier, but is there anyother toolkits like gtk or frameworks like qt to server better?

Comment: Define *better*. The answer will depend on the specification.

Comment: If there is nothing to quantify, this is a subjective question. What are your requirements? What languages should the toolkit support? Is tooling necessary? Does it have to be cross-platform? What's wrong with the available tools? What specific platform is your target? Does it recommend a toolkit?

Comment: I'd say Qt is your best bet, but I'm not giving any reasons because you didn't give any criteria...

Comment: @andref:Support for c,c++,python.
it needs to works on linux.Tools like X11,GTK are hard and complex, linux is my specific platform,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the richest possible GUI framework. This way you will eliminate lots of unnecessary code and reuse existing functionalities.

If you'll take above into consideration, you'll have two options (dropping GTK because of complexity as you say, and bunch of other less maintained and less popular toolkits):

- Qt
- WxWidgets

I've worked with both and both share somewhat similar concepts, but IMHO Qt is better documented, better maintained, and is used by far more developers than WxWidgets, plus it have more sophisticated tools like QtCreator, etc.
On the other hand I like that WxWidgets  has *manual* programming approach, where you're practically forced to build the GUI from code.

One very important thing to mention:

> Qt has [support for embedded
>   Linux](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Support_for_Embedded_Linux), eliminating the need for
>   X11.

Some literature:

- [WxWidgets Compared To Other Toolkits](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Compared_To_Other_Toolkits)
- [...and other Google results](http://www.google.com/#q=qt+vs+wxwidgets)

Comment: Plus Python support via PySide, an "official" Python binding: http://www.pyside.org/